# Is $h:x\to \exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2}\right]\left(\exp\left[\frac{x^4}{24n}\right]-1\right)$ increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

I struggling to show this function ins increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$

$$h:x\to \exp\left[-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right]\left(\exp\left[\dfrac{x^4}{24n}\right]-1\right) \qquad n\in \mathbb{N}^*$$

With the derivative

I've found

$$h'(x)=xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\left[\left(\dfrac{x^2}{6n}-1\right)e^{\frac{x^4}{24n}}+1\right]$$

$h'(x)\ge 0\iff \left(\dfrac{x^2}{6n}-1\right)e^{\frac{x^4}{24n}}+1\ge 0$

and now I'm blocked...

Comment: What is the parameter $n$?

Comment: $$n\in \mathbb{N}^*$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$h'(x)=-xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(e^{\frac{x^4}{24n}}-1\right)+\frac{x^3}{6n}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{x^4}{24n}}
=-xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}\right)e^{\frac{x^4}{24n}}-1\right)$$

then we need to prove that

$$\left(\frac{x^2}{6n}-1\right)e^{\frac{x^4}{24n}}+1 \ge 0 $$

and for $\frac{x^2}{6n}-1<0 \iff x<\sqrt{6n}$ it is equivalent to

$$\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6n}\right)e^{\frac{x^4}{24n}}-1\le 0 $$

and by $y=\frac{x^2}{6n}\in (0,1)$

$$(1-y)e^{\frac32ny^2}-1\le 0 $$

which doesn't hold for $n=2$ indeed

$$f(y)=(1-y)e^{3y^2}-1 \implies f'(y)=e^{3y^2}(-6y^2+6y-1)=0 \implies y_{1,2}=\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}6$$

and $f(y_1)>0$.